# PHPMYADMIN - How do allow a user to create a database, but only show the db's created by that user?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Question says it all, but to clarify:
I can only create a database when the `create` is set - this is obvious, however as soon as I do all the databases show up in the left column.

As soon as I remove the remove this option to `create` it only shows the DB that the user has access to controlled by the root user.

**I want a user to be able to create a database, but not see all the db's that are created**

In Terminal I can create them, but I want to use phpmyadmin so that not everyone needs to use the terminal interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a trcik to it. You can allow your users to create database which start by a specific name lets say `testdatabase`. And then you can set the previleges like this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdatabase\_%` .  * TO 'testuser'@'%';
```

So this will allow the `testuser` to have access to all the database which are having the name like `testdatabase_`

Comment: so if joe wants to create a db called test01 then the syntax would be: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON` `testdatabase\test01%` .  `* TO 'joe'@'%';` ?

Comment: @JeffKranenburg:- Indeed.!

Comment: Cool will try it out in about a bit (after dinner :-)) and accept if it works alright :-)

Comment: Thanks - that will do fine :-) Also +1 for easy explanation